# Trying to implement single page functionality with traditional asp.net MVC, Razor and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, single-page-application

I just want to run this by some of you. the default scaffolding for an MVC 4 project in VS 2012 assumes that your list, detail, create, edit, delete pages are all seperate.

I have created one page that handles all of those functions for a primary model entity and its related entities.

The part that's got me a little concerned is how I'm segmenting this functionality.

The user interacts with the page through divs like this

```
<div id="createtrace">click</div>
```

which fires some JS that appends the div's id to the form data...

```
$("#createtrace").click(function () {
    $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
          .attr('name', "action")
          .attr('value', "ct")
          .appendTo('#frm');
    $("#frm").submit();
});
```

I then have a switch in the controller that routes the action to the correct block of code, like this...

```
string action = Request.Form["action"].ToString();
switch (action)
{
    case "ct":
        trace trace = new trace();
        trace.bookingid = vwbooking.bookings.bookingid;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.traces.Add(trace);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        break;
    case "ut":
        vwbooking.traces.ToList().ForEach(
            t =>
            {
                db.traces.Attach(t);
                db.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            );
        db.SaveChanges();
    break;
 }
```

does this seem reasonable? Am I bastardizing the routing engine? Recreating the wheel?

Comment: What is the goal? Same Url all the time or no page reloads or something else?

Comment: My background is web forms. I could use a listview to handle the life cycle of an entity - create, edit, delete. There would be a page refresh, but you're still able to stay on the same page. The mvc model seems to want to separate interactions into different views - I want one view.  

Take a contact record. I want a new a button along with a list of existing records. When I click on a record, I want it show the detail right there, editable, along with a list of that contact's list of phone numbers, from which I can add, edit and delete.

Comment: If you want one view and don't care about urls/refresh - just use one view... Not sure what is the problem than ( `return View("MyOnlyView");`)...

Comment: Problem is my lack of experience in MVC/Routing. I understand this particular issue now, and yes, I can use the default routing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better just create an action per action. Make your JavaScript post to the appropriate URL, like /CreateTrace/.

Comment: This makes sense, and its what I tried initially, but I thought I had to return a view with the same name... I'll take another look.

Comment: My mistake was in trying to return view without specifying a view name. My action name doesn't have to match a view name, as long as I provide the view name I want it to use.